# Firefox не правильно позиционирует th:after

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Здравствуйте. Для упрощения есть след. код:

```
th{
position:relative;
}
th:after{
  content: '';
  width:20%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
}
```

В mozilla firefox псевдоэлемент :after не смотря на position:relative у родителя позиционируется от краев окна браузера. Кто-нибуть сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как её решить?
В chrome и opera позиционирование относительно родителя как и должно быть. 
Версии браузеров самые последние. Разметка в порядке. ОС - Windows 8.

Comment: проблема именно с th:after

Comment: выложите код на jsfiddle, очень интересно взглянуть

Comment: Разметка обычная html таблица.
css приведен в вопросе. пробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается это очень древний баг FF. Мозилла не понимает `positin:relative` для ячеек таблицы. Решил эту проблему вложенным в ячейки таблицы дивами. Относительно их и позиционировал.

Comment: + Точно так же и я выкручивался

Answer (score 1):

также не работает для блоков c `display:table`, `display:table-cell`

Comment: [пруф-тест][http://jsfiddle.net/XKLS7/]